# Cannot connect to TIdHTTPServer from TIdHTTP in delphi

Tags: delphi, indy, httpserver

I have an application with `TIdHTTPServer` and `TIdHTTP` in delphi and I have this code :

```
// This is for activating the HTTPServer - works as expected
HTTPServer1.Bindings.Add.IP := '127.0.0.1';
HTTPServer1.Bindings.Add.Port := 50001;
HTTPServer1.Active := True;
```

This is the `OnCommandGet` procedure of my HTTPServer :

```
procedure TDataForm.HttpServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
  AResponseInfo.ContentText := 'Hello, user';
end;
```

And I just don't know why this procedure isn't working :

```
procedure TDataForm.btnHTTPSendGetClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  HTTPClient : TIdHTTP;
  responseStream : TMemoryStream;
begin
  HTTPClient := TIdHTTP.Create;
  responseStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    try
      HTTPClient.Get('http://127.0.0.1:50001', responseStream);
    except on e : Exception do begin
      showmessage('Could not send get request to localhost, port 50001');
    end;
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(HTTPClient);
    FreeAndNil(responseStream);
  end;
end;
```

If I connect via browser I can see in the browser 'Hello, user', but if I try `btnHTTPSendGetClick` my program crashes with no exception or anything. Can anyone help me fix my code ?

Comment: Which version of Delphi and Indy are you using? How is your code crashing without an exception?

Comment: @Remy, I'm using Indy 10 on Delphi XE5 and I explained about the crashing right after your answer. I tried all your suggestions but it's still crashing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> HTTPServer1.Bindings.Add.IP := '127.0.0.1';
>   HTTPServer1.Bindings.Add.Port := 50001;

This is a common newbie mistake.  You are creating two bindings, one bound to 127.0.0.1:DefaultPort, and one bound to 0.0.0.0:50001.  You need one binding instead, that is bound to 127.0.0.1:50001 instead.

```
with HTTPServer1.Bindings.Add do begin
  IP := '127.0.0.1';
  Port := 50001;
end;
```

Or:

```
HTTPServer1.Bindings.Add.SetBinding('127.0.0.1', 50001, Id_IPv4);
```

Or:

```
HTTPServer1.DefaultPort := 50001;
HTTPServer1.Bindings.Add.IP := '127.0.0.1';
```

With that said, your server response is incomplete.  Try this instead:

```
procedure TDataForm.HttpServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
  AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 200;
  AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'text/plain';
  AResponseInfo.ContentText := 'Hello, user';
end;
```

Comment: `How is it crashing without an exception?` - well, you know - my form gets foggy and says `(Not Responding)` and after a couple of minutes it's still the same so I have to kill it manually.

Comment: @Roman_Bezjak: that means that your application is locked in a busy loop and that it can't respond to window messages...

Comment: @whosrdaddy I see.. Well I just have no idea how to fix this :(

Comment: @whosrdaddy and @Remy - I fixed it, it turned out that while I was testing I was trying to change a `TMemo` without using `TIdCriticalSection` - after I removed it it works perfectly. Thanks for the prompt and adequate assistance, guys :)

Comment: You can't protect access to UI controls using a critical section, that just does not work. You have to sync with the main thread instead so that the main thread is the only thread directly accessing the UI. Other threads wanting to touch the UI have to ask the main thread to do so on their behalf.